# i need my menu bar to close automatically when i click anywhere else on the page

Tags: jquery, menu

How do i make the menu automatically close when i click anywhere else on the page. Please help. Thanks.

```
$('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function(){
            $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
            $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
            $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```js
$('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function() {
  $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
  $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
  $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
});

$('*').on('click', function() {
      if ($("#theMenu").hasClass("menu-open") {
          //to bad :(
        } else {
          $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
          $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
          $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```